# Phonegap: Can't get a simple alert box to work

Tags: cordova

I am trying to do a simple alert box using Phonegap and it has being real difficult. After I've watched a lot of tutorials I can't get this to work and also emulators and in-device testing doesn't work properly.

So I have drawn 3 divs and each one is a box with a different color. Then I tried to do a simple alert box on each one when I click it, with a different code. When Eclipse loads the Apk into my phone it does not build the current working version and sometimes it does. When it does I can try the application to then realise that none of the click events have worked.

Here is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="DOMloaded()">
        <div id="box" onclick="funcClick()"></div>

        <div id="box2"></div>

        <div id="box3"></div>



        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.css

```
#box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#box2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;  
}

#box3 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;  
}
```

index.js

```
function DOMloaded() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", phonegapLoaded, false);
}

function phonegapLoaded() {
    function funcClick() {
        alert("Yellow box onclick event");
    };
    $("#box2").click(function() {
        alert("Red box jQuery click event");
    });
    $("#box3").on('touchstart', function() {
        alert("Blue box jQuery and Phonegap touch event");
    });
    alert("Events loaded");
}
```

The only thing that has work is the `alert("Events loaded").`

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined "funcClick" in local scope (in scope of "phonegapLoaded" function), so it doesn't work on div click. I can't give good explanation (maybe someone will explain in comments) why nothing happens with box2 and box3, but i have work solution:

```
function funcClick () {
    alert("Yellow box onclick event");
};

function phonegapLoaded () {
    $(document).on("click", "#box2", function(){
        alert("Red box jQuery click event");
    });

    $(document).on('touchstart', "#box3", function (){
        alert("Blue box jQuery and Phonegap touch event");
    });
    alert("Events loaded");
}
```

Comment: The onClick has worked but when I install in my phone it has those 300ms of delay and can't use those click and touchstart even if I use the global scope. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3062745 i spend and spend time trying to figure out how to improve perfomance of Cordova + JQM application (including no tap delays). But still i can't say anything useful about it

Comment: @user3062745 what and how?

Comment: It was the compiling that was not working, I set it up wrong.